# .dropUnit on .hlist'ed codecs doesnt seem to work

Tags: scala, shapeless, scodec

For "big" codecs, the Scala phase typer takes forever (we're talking minutes) when creating a codec directly from `HList`s and applying `.dropUnits`

```
( ignore(6) ::
  uint(2) ::
  uint(30) ::
  int(4) ::
  int(8) ::
  uint(10) ::
  bool(1) ::
  int(28) ::
  int(27) ::
  uint(12) ::
  uint(9) ::
  uint(6) ::
  int(2) ::
  ignore(3) ::
  bool(1) ::
  uint(19)
).dropUnits.as[SomeBigCaseClass]
```

And it seems to be way faster to create a codec with `~`, and then applying `.hlist` like such:

```
( ignore(6) ~
  uint(2) ~
  ...
).hlist.dropUnits.as[SomeBigCaseClass]
```

But this doesn't seem work.

```
Could not prove that this.Out can be converted to/from reports.SomeBigCaseClass.
  ).hlist.dropUnits.as[SomeBigCaseClass]
                      ^
```

The simplest solution I've found, which is good enough for me is omitting `Unit` values inline.

```
( (ignore(6) dropLeft 
   uint(2)) :: 
  ...
).as[SomeBigCaseClass]
```

For codecs with many ignores, this feature would be highly welcome. What am I doing wrong? Am I totally missing the point of `.hlist`?

Comment: It seems that `.hlist` only wraps the codec in a `HList`, and that's ok, but that doesn't really solve the issue of the slow phase typer when `.dropUnits  ` on a sized `HList` is invoked.

Comment: And also, since `~>` takes precedence over `::`, the parantheses surrounding the `.dropLeft` statement can be ommitted when using the `~>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hlist` combinator converts a `Codec[A]` in to a `Codec[A :: HNil]`. This is typically used with other combinators, like `flatZip`, which require an `HList` based codec.

Repeated use of the `~` operator creates a left-associated `Tuple2` based structure. For example, `int8 ~ bool ~ int8` has type `Codec[((Int, Boolean), Int)]`. The latest scodec snapshot, 1.7.0-SNAPSHOT (though not 1.7.0-RC1), has the `flattenLeftPairs` method, which converts a left associated tuple codec to an equivalent `HList` codec.

A future version of scodec will have a combinator like `~` but rather than nesting `Tuple2` instances, it will create `TupleN` instances. For example: `int8 ~~ bool ~~ int8` would have type `Codec[(Int, Boolean, Int)]`. This has not been integrated yet though. This has both a performance advantage, by reducing the number of tuples allocated, as well as a convenience advantage, because it allows binding to case classes via `widenOpt(SomeBigCaseClass.apply, SomeBigCaseClass.unapply)`.

Finally, the observed compiler performance problem with `dropUnits` is indeed a problem with the way that combinator is defined. This has been fixed in scodec-core 1.7.0-SNAPSHOT (not 1.7.0-RC1 though). See https://github.com/scodec/scodec/issues/41.

Comment: Yes, it was rather unobservant of me to fail to the type signature of the `.hlist` before posting the questing. Thanks for the clarifications on the performance issue! - And massive thanks for a great job on the lib, btw.